# Can't define a private static final variable because it throws an exception

Tags: java, exception, initialization

I have a class like:

```
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
   private static final SomeLib someLib = new SomeLib();
}
```

I can't do this because SomeLib throws a UnknownHostException.

I know I could move the instantiation to the constructor, but is there a way for me to do it the way I have it above somehow?  That way I can keep the var marked as final.

I tried to look for how to throw exceptions at the class level but can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use static initializer:

```
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
   private static final SomeLib someLib;
   static {
     SomeLib tmp = null;
     try {
       tmp = new SomeLib();
     } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
       // Handle exception.
     }
     someLib = tmp;
   }
}
```

Note that we need to use a temporary variable to avoid "variable someLib might not have been initialized" error and to cope with the fact that we can only assign `someLib` once due to it being `final`.

However, the need to add complex initialization logic and exception handling to static initializer is often a sign of a more fundamental design issue. You wrote in the comments section that this is a database connection pool class. Instead of using static final consider making it an instance variable. You can then do the initialization in a constructor or better yet in a static factory method.

Comment: My answer exactly, but yours is with code and was posted seconds before mine. 1+ up-vote.

Comment: but this library actually is a connection pool into a database, i'm weary of creating a temporary variable in case it creates 2 instances of this pool?

Comment: btw, how can I force the caller to catch the exception when creating this SomeClassImpl class?  I can't figure out how to throw at the class level.

Comment: In Java all non-primitive variables are references, so there is only a single SomeLib instance here with both tmp and someLib referring to that single instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating the class"? Instatiating or loading? As for instantiation you can force your client to handle exception by declaring that constructor throws a checked exception. As for loading: if you can't handle your exception in the static initializer, you should probably not let it be thrown by not making the field static.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a static initializer:

```
private static final SomeLib SOME_LIB; // respect naming conventions

static {
    try {
        SOME_LIB = new SomeLib();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Class initialization failed due to UnknownHostException", e);
    }
}
```

Note that your class won't be able to initialize if you do it so. Maybe you should try to initialize the lib lazily, when needed. Such class initialization exceptions are hard to diagnose, because they're transformed into ClassNotFoundException or NoClassDefFoundError (I don't remember which one)

Comment: This would result in crashing the application as well!

Comment: Yes, I prefer to let it crash immediately rather than to wait for a NullPointerException to happen. If the application must not crash, it would be preferrable to initialize the field lazily, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree with you, but that is exactly what he doesn't want...

If you ask me using a final static field like this, that throws an exception in the constructor, is bad architecture, it should not be implemented this way, except for very rare reasons...

Answer (score 2):

Even just a little bit more elegant than the solution from [Adam Zalcman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023815/adam-zalcman):

```
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
   private static final SomeLib someLib = initSomeLib();

   private static SomeLib initSomeLib() {
     SomeLib someLib = null;
     try {
       someLib = new SomeLib();
     } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
       // Handle exception.
     }
     return someLib;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If initialising a variable is likely to fail, then it is likely a poor candidate to be static.

Statics are good for [effective] immutables, (with care) caches of immutables and little else.

Comment: so then what are you suggesting I do?  This is a mongodb class (Mongo) which is a connection pool into the db.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will gives you an idea on initializing multiple varibales with out using static method:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeOtherClass{

private String string1= getValues("/var/log/log1.txt");
private String component = getValues("/var/log/log2.txt");

private String getValues(String file) {
        try {
          return  new Scanner(new File(file)).next();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ioe){
            System.out.println("File not found :: " +ioe);
        }
        return null;
    }
```